# searching through text files then printing the data

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, search, input

im making a bus reservation system and i dont know how to search through the text file and then printing the data.

here's how its supposed to work:

user enters a name and the date of travel

the program searches through the text file to find a line that matches with the name and date of travel

if the program finds it, it will print the number of tickets, name, departure city, destination city, date of travel, time of travel

here's my whole code so far

```
restart = 'Y'

while restart != ('y'):
    passenger = open("reservation.txt" , "a+")

    print("\n1. Make Reservation")

    print("2. Modify Reservation")

    print("3. Cancel Reservation")

    print("4. Search Reservation")

    print("5. Exit")

    option = int(input("\nEnter your option: "))


    if option == 1: //makes reservation
        passenger.write("\n")
        tickets = input("\nNumber of Tickets: ")
        space = len(tickets)+1
        passenger.write(tickets.ljust(space))

        name = input("\nPassenger Name: ")
        space = len(name)+1
        passenger.writelines(name.ljust(space))

        departure  = input("\nDeparture City: ")
        space = len(departure)+1
        passenger.writelines(departure.ljust(space))

        destination  = input("\nDestination City: ")
        space = len(destination)+1
        passenger.writelines(destination.ljust(space))

        date = input("\nDate of Travel: ")
        space = len(date)+1
        passenger.writelines(date.ljust(space))

        time = input("\nTime of Travel: ")
        space = len(time)+1
        passenger.writelines(departure.ljust(space))

        print("Your reservation has been submitted. \nThank you!")
        restart = input("Try again? (y/n): ").upper()
        passenger.close()
        if restart == ('N'):
            exit(0)

    elif option == 2:
        //edits reservation

    elif option == 3:
        //cancels reservation

    elif option == 4: //searches through the reservations
        passenger = open("reservation.txt" , "r+")
        n = input("Enter passenger name: ")
            #dt = input("Date of Travel: ")
        if n in passenger.read():
            x = 0
            for i in range(1, x, 1):   
                contents = passenger.readlines(i)
                print(contents)
        else:
            print('doesnt exist')

        restart = input("Try again? (y/n): ").upper()
        passenger.close()
        if restart == ('N'):
            exit(0)  

    elif option == 5:
        exit(0)

    else:
        print('invalid input')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. Did you have a question? Does your solution work? Is it deficient? If so, how is it deficient? Do you suspect any part of it? Why? Have you presented us with a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open("reservation.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if name in line and date in line: # name and date are the variables you're looking for
            print(line)
            break
```

You make a list of lines and then use the `in` keyword to search through each line in that list.

```
>>> 'python' in 'hello world this is python'
True
```